# Efficient Database Structure for Deep Tree Data

Tags: sql, database-design, tree, hashmap, bloom-filter

For a very big data database (more than a billion rows) where there is a very deep data tree, what is the most efficient structure?  The read loading is the highest usage, but there are also changes to the tree on a regular basis.

There are several standard algorithms to represent a data tree.  I have found this reference as part of the Mongodb manual to be an excellent summary: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

My system has properties that do not map well to any of these cases.  The issue is that the depth of the tree is so great that keeping "ancestors" or a "path" is very large.  The tree also changes frequently enough that the "Nested Sets" approach is not efficient.  I am considering a hybrid of the "Materialized Paths" and "Parent References" approach, where instead of the path I store a hash that is not guaranteed to be unique, but 90% of the time it is.  Then the 10% of the time there is a collision, the parent reference resolves it.  The idea is that the 90% of the time there is a fast query for the path hash.  This idea is kind of like a bloom filter technique.  But this is all for background: the question is in the first line of this post.

Comment: Could you please be more precise about what you mean by "read loading"?

Comment: I meant queries vs inserts, I should have said that.  I mean that there are regular inserts into the DB, but the majority of accesses are queries.  What is important is that this is not a static tree, inserts can happen anywhere in the tree, but 70% of access is for queries.

Comment: What kind of queries? Getting the whole tree (out of the "wood")? Getting (direct) children of given node? Getting (recursive) descendants of given node? Getting (direct) parent of given node? Getting (all) ancestors of given node?

Comment: All of these cases.  Think of it as a file explorer, where each "insert" represents file metadata.  The DB is effectively a mapping from a file tree to a back-end server farm.  Files can be added to the "farm" but never removed, but state can be updated.  Another term for this structure is "global namespace" where you have to query the whole, or specific nodes, children etc.  Does that help explain?  - Update: It is infrequent where the whole tree will be queried as anyone doing so would have to expect a delay.  They are putting files into a specific "directory", which is a node in the DB.

Comment: In short, thinking of windows explorer from the user perspective, you click on "directories" and a GUI shows the files and sub-directories.  As you click down a path, the DB will be queried for the file metadata.  When you copy a file, then the database is queried for data that tells the system where to find the file.  It is outside of my question why or what this is for, but I think that information should help.  This file tree can be extremely deep.

Comment: You have just described the "get direct children" case. This can be done quite efficiently in a relational database by just using the [adjacency list model](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data), especially if you are careful about [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering).

Comment: Ok, given my question scope, this is a reasonable answer, but I think the weakness is "careful about clustering".  From my analysis so far, NoSql databases have built in horizontal scaling.  This means that in this case I don't have to be "careful about clustering", because it is built into the database architecture. Regarding the "adjacency list model" I will give this more thought.  Perhaps I have been overly concerned about tree depth.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Please read the link about clustering. I meant something quite different from "horizontal scaling" by it.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past with arbitrarily deep trees is just to store a Parent Key with each, as well as a sequence number which governs the order of children under a parent. I used RDBM's and this worked very efficiently. To arrange the tree structure after reading required code to arrange things properly - put each node in a Child collection in the nodes parent - but this in fact ran pretty fast.

It's a pretty naieve approach, in that there's nothing clever about it, but it does work for me.

The tree had about 300 or 400 members total and was I think 7 or 8 levels deep. This part of the system had no performance problems at all: it was very fast. The UI was a different matter, but that's another story.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't this a very small DB?  400 members by 8 levels deep is tiny, isn't it?  My problem is not finding a functional solution, but finding a blazing efficient solution.  I have a billion "members", unless I'm misunderstanding your definition for "members"?

Comment: OK, you did say a billion members in the Q. But that's not something that can be taken for granted (people on SO say all sorts of things). You need to make it a bit more believable - like 'billion data points from so-and-so'. Otherwise people might think that you're building the new Facebook (they all seem to be building 'Social Sites') and in all probability it'll never see more than their family. So apologies; this answer isn't appropriate.

Comment: PS I guess you've already looked, but the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure)#Representations has some alternatives.

Comment: It is not for Facebook but it is a major project that is quite large.  It may be a bit strange to be posting a question here for such a massive system, as clearly there is a lot of expertise and knowledge, and engineers working such a system.  But I'm the lead and I'm getting my feet wet with the overall architectural issues.  I will soon be meeting with major development teams who will be trying to sell me their database solution.  I don't want to go into those meetings without having done my homework.  So this question is  based on research to date on the topic.  Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: I also should mention that my question has a lot more knowledge behind it.  I am looking for a sanity check on my thinking.  For example, I believe NoSQL solutions, especially Cassandra database, may allow for hashing and bloom filter approaches that I don't have to deal with in my business logic.  Cassandra also solves my need for horizontal scaling and redundancy.  I will be meeting with their database experts and I'll update this question with my findings.